# Different series or movie that used the spaceship from the movie "Sphere"

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship, sphere

I am really bothered by the thought about the ship being showed once in a series, but I couldn't find the series again.  I remember watching a movie or a series where the story of the crew was shown but I couldn't find it anywhere. Maybe someone can help me?

Comment: When and where would you have seen this?  Were the production standards high, or was it b-movie quality?

Comment: I remember watching it back in 2014/2015. It was more like a stereotypical series from beginnig of 2000's or end of 1990's.

Comment: Just reused props, or an actual sequel/prequel directly tied to the movie?

Comment: http://www.modelshipsinthecinema.com/2016/08/sphere-1998.html - I can't find any mention of McCune models using the ship again

Comment: It was more like a "prequel" about what happened in the future. But what also interesting is, that the fin on the spaceship had a checkers board pattern and the spaceship I remember also had a similar pattern.

Comment: There was, as far as I'm aware, no prequel to Sphere, nor have there been any other works set in the same fictional universe.

Comment: Damn, but I am really sure that I've seen it... Idk but maybe you know what I mean, don't you? I remember it pretty well like my fingers on my hands but it serms like it just disappeared...